# SQL Exam need help to write SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a SQL exam question that need help

System A :
Student Details
1. Student Full Name
2. Subject Applied
3. Level ( level1,  level2 , level 3)

System B:
Students Information 
1. Student Full  Name 
2. Address
3. Tel. No
4. Parent's Name

Now,  the project is to create a "System C ",  which is a simple software that actually combine both information from System A and System B into System C

Write a SQL query which fulfill the above statement

Thanks
Kelly

Comment: Hint: read about join, natural join, left outer join (probably most appropriate approach)

Comment: we are not here to write your homework. try to write your code, google your problems and if you couldn't find a solution we will help you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to `JOIN` the two tables together to produce a combined result. Below will combine these two tables using the common field `student_full_name`.

```
select
 b.student_full_name, b.address, b.number, b.parent_name, a.subject, a.level
from SYSTEM_A as a

inner join SYSTEM_B as b ON a.student_full_name = b.student_full_name
;
```

If you need to create a new table with the combined result, prefix the above query with `CREATE TABLE SYSTEM_C`